# Android reverse geocoding service exception

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to make the example: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/location/geocoding.html#TaskReverseGeocoding.

Works but actually I got

> Service not Available exception

when trying to retrive the address, I've got through this and got the API key and all this stuff but nothing changed, and it doesn't work even on the device itself!

Answer (score 2):

```
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault()); 
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        if (addresses.size() > 0) {
            String address = "";
            for (int index = 0; index < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); index++)
                address += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(index) + " ";
            tv.setText(address);                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+address,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.v("AddressTag", address);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: Didn't work :
actually the code you posted is similar to the example ,actually getting the coordinates latitude, longitude is working but it through IO exception:service not available  in the address part !!